# Webview showing unwanted dialog

Tags: java, android, url, webview

I am trying to open webpage in webview. Page loaded successfully but sometimes it shows dialog to **install UC browser** as display in below screen.

Screenshot of Dialog

[image]

Below is Code:

```
webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
                //Required functionality here
                return super.onJsAlert(view, url, message, result);
            }

        });


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        }

        webView.setWebViewClient(new AppWebViewClients());
        webView.loadUrl("page_url");
```

I have to enable java script because there are few validation in page.

Comment: Are you using UC browser?

Comment: @ShanmugavelGK No. In my phone only chrome and device default browser is installed. Both I cannot uninstall.

Comment: `onJsAlert` have you tried setting breakpoint in this method to check if it is the one showing message?

Comment: @Nirav chances are there that the website being tried to open had malicious code that is creating this dialog. Such dialog usually, i guess as i am not into web, exploits javascripts. Try checking the site for any unwanted scripts.

Comment: this is mostly a redirection adware on a particular site. most of the time, you can't do anything about those popups, except closing that tab.

Comment: Which URL are you trying to load in WebView ? The problem may cause from the site ...

Comment: @RRTW It is company's private web url, through which end user can submit their data. Popup only opens in few devices not on all devices. I am using POCO F1 phone.

Answer (score 0):

please try using this

```
public void setWebViewClient(WebViewClient client) {
mWebViewClient = client;
```

}

instead of setWebChromeClient

if you are developing a WebView that won't require too many features but rendering HTML, you can just use a WebViewClient

Comment: I have to put chrome client because there validation for mandatory fields. When user click on Submit button in webview, it will display dialog box with message.

Comment: did you added these two lines
webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
webview.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());

Comment: I have put code in my question. Yes I have added both lines

Answer (score 0):

try this to webview

```
webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);
```

Comment: which kinda issue ?

Comment: same dialog display to install UC browser.

Answer (score 0):

I asked some other guy who had exactly same issue, maybe you can try :

- Check Server side JS file or any other plugin
- Check if any other installed app, which package name like **com.UCMobile.** , try to disable or uninstall them.

Comment: OK. Captcha is there. I think due to captcha code it showing uc browser dialog.